# send an image from java program to android program using sockets in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to send a jpeg image file from java program client to android program server using TCP sockets in eclipse IDE.
here is my android server code:

```
package com.example.ando;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

      ImageView ve;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ve=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picture);

    }
    public void gotit(View vw)
    {
        byte[] mybytearray  = new byte[310000];
        int bytesRead=0;
        int current = 0;

        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        Socket servers;


        try {
             serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);
                servers = serverSocket.accept();
                servers.setSoTimeout(10000);
           File myDir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/saved_images");

            if (!myDir.exists()){
                myDir.mkdir();
            }else{
                Log.d("ServerActivity","Folder Already created" );
            }

            String fpath = "/image0001.jpg";
            File file = new File (myDir, fpath);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();


            InputStream is = servers.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            current = bytesRead;

            do {
                bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
                if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
            } while(bytesRead > -1);

            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(mybytearray);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            ve = new ImageView(this);
            ve.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);

            Log.d("ServerActivity","Reconstructing Image from array");

            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            is.close();
            servers.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace();
  }



    }


}
```

My xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ando.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_material" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_below="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="gotit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Manifest file has following permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ando"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My java client code is:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Robot;
 import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReadParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.*;

public class ConvertImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
           DataOutputStream dos;
          PrintWriter out;
           ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
            BufferedImage buffimg;
           BufferedImage image;

               byte[] imageInByte;
           try
             { 
          Socket clients=new Socket("10.0.0.2",9000);
             Robot robot=new Robot();

            buffimg = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            image = buffimg;


            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
            baos.flush();
            imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();

             dos = new DataOutputStream(clients.getOutputStream());
            out = new PrintWriter(clients.getOutputStream());

            out.println("!SCREENDATA!");
            out.flush();
            dos.writeInt(baos.toByteArray().length);
            dos.write(baos.toByteArray());
            dos.flush();
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

}
```

In java code i have this problem:

```
C:\Users\ABTILAK\Desktop\dos pracs>javac ConvertImage.java

C:\Users\ABTILAK\Desktop\dos pracs>java ConvertImage
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at ConvertImage.main(ConvertImage.java:39)
```

I may be facing other code problems as well.
Anybody plz. help and thank you in advance...

Comment: I had similar issue, it was due to firewall on windows. Check that.

Comment: `Connection timed out` means that it took too much time for the `response`. It is probably du to the `Server`. Check `Server` if it is handling image correctly

Comment: you are not calling gotit() anywhere in your activity

Comment: But I m calling gotit in Onclick xml

Comment: Where is your Android server running? Device/emulator? Where is your java client running? PC? Your java client uses 10.0.2.2. That looks wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a late reply but i got this code working by placing the android code into async task along with modifications and then i am passing the image from java program into android by converting into bytes. You can also use executor service rather than simple threads in the data transfer.